# Какая тут рекуррентная формула

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, формулы

Помогите решить задачу не пойму какая тут формула

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит какая рекурсия?

Comment: не могу выяснить формулу в стиле третий элемент = второй + первый

Comment: А С++ тут при чем?

Comment: потому что потом еще программу на с++ писать по задаче аа ее срочно решить надо и вот для больше охвата

Comment: @AlbionMuz мог бы переписать условие и перевести на русский. Для больше охвата так сказать. А не просто скрины в таком качестве выложить и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, право, элементарно же, Ватсон!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при  *x*<sub>1</sub>=1, *x*<sub>2</sub>=2

Тупая реализация (но для небольших *n* нормально сработает:

```
double f(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    if (n == 2) return 2;
    return f(n-2)/sqrt(f(n-1));
}
```

Посчитать - вообще нефиг делать...

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 0.707107
4: 2.37841
5: 0.458502
6: 3.5125
7: 0.244643
```

Comment: ты лучший чувак!!

Comment: Не сказал бы, что "чувак" звучит как комплимент... :)

Comment: запятую забыл + там ошибка в паре символов в реализации

Comment: Да, есть такое... Исправляюсь.